# How can I write a Unix script to quickly start a service on multiple remote servers?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I am trying to run an application on multiple (~20) Unix servers. Rather than SSH'ing into each one individually, I would like to log in to one and use a script to start them all up.

The application does not require any direct user interaction, so I essentially just need to run './app arg1 arg2' on each machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One improvement on straight SSH is to start SSH session in the background and then `wait` for all of them to finish.  This way you can execute command on remote servers simultaneously.

We use this technique in our production scripts.

```
function start_server ( )
{
  ssh $1 '/path/to/start_service_script'
}

echo "Starting servers"
for serv_name in $( cat /path/to/server-list )
do
    # I usually declare a function, because if SSH command
    # gets more elaborate ( especially if it has ampersands
    # as part of the command, the shell has trouble parsing 
    # the background push (& at the end of the command)
    #
    # In this particular case it would be no trouble to
    # inline ssh here
    start_server ${serv_name} &
done

echo
# Very important to wait till all the spawned processes finish
wait
```

One thing to note, because all spawned processes are running simultaneously and using the same console, you may see some interleaved output on your screen.

Comment: If you use a fibonacci tree instead of your star topology, you can reduce the load on your primary host and also speed up the time to complete broadcast propagation. Nevertheless, +1 for the `&` idea :)

Comment: @bitmask. For ~20 servers ( as for OP request ), I don't really see a load problem for a central server.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use ssh, and if you set properly public keys onto your servers, you won't have to enter passwords :

```
for host in hosts
do
   ssh user@$host "./app arg1 arg2"
done
```

Otherwise, you could use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/index.html) to help you to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
omnissh() { for s in $(cat /server/list) ; do ssh $s "$@" ; done }

omnissh /etc/init.d/service start
```